# Select item from typeahead with enter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3, bootstrap-typeahead

Good day, I'm trying to add an event to my typeahead. Please check my script first

JavaScript

```
$("#itemid").typeahead({
source: function(query, process) {
     $.ajax({
         async:true,
         url: '<?=base_url();?>do_mutasi/ItemList/'+$("#tipenya").val()+'/'+ $("#itemid").val().replace(/ /g,"_"),
         dataType: 'JSON',
         success: function(data) {
                  process(data);
                }               
        });
    },
  minLength: 3
});
```

PHP

```
public function ItemList($tipe="",$itemid=""){
            extract(populateform());
            $newitemid = str_replace("' '",'_',$itemid);
            $hasil = $this->modelmodel->showdata("SELECT ItemCode,ItemName from Item 
                                                where status = 1
                                                and (ItemCode like '%".$itemid."%' or ItemName like '%".$newitemid."%') and ItemType like '%".$tipe."%' 
                                                ");
            $data = array();
            foreach ($hasil as $hsl)
                {
                    $data[] = $hsl->ItemCode .' [ '. $hsl->ItemName . ' ] ' ;
                }
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

and my HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipe</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select required size="1" class="form-control" id="tipenya">
                        <?php 
                        if(isset($tipeitem->ItemType)){ 
                            if(rtrim(ltrim($tipeitem->ItemType)) == "MERCHANDISE"){
                                echo " <option value='MERCHANDISE'>MERCHANDISE</option>";
                            }else if(rtrim(ltrim($tipeitem->ItemType)) == "GENERAL"){
                                echo " <option  value='GENERAL'>GENERAL</option>";
                            }
                            else{
                            echo    "<option  value='MERCHANDISE'>MERCHANDISE</option>
                                    <option value='GENERAL'>GENERAL</option>";
                            }
                        }
                            else{
                            echo    "<option  value='MERCHANDISE'>MERCHANDISE</option>
                                    <option value='GENERAL'>GENERAL</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Kode Item</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <input required type="search" autocomplete="off" name="dest" id="itemid" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." data-provide="typeahead" />             </div>
                  </div>
```

Data example from php result from my browser console.

```
["F160048 [ FLT SHOES L27506 BLUE ] ","F160049 [ FLT SHOES L27506 GREEN ] ","F160050 [ FLT SHOES L27506
 ORANGE ] "]
```

There isn't any problem with my script above. I just want to adding `enter` event. How can i achieve that ? Sorry for my bad english

I found the problem my problem is because my Js below. Which is the function from my script below for change textfield if i press `enter`

```
$('body').on('keydown', 'input, select, textarea', function(e) {
var self = $(this)
  , form = self.parents('form:eq(0)')
  , focusable
  , next
  ;
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible');
        next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this)+1);
        if (next.length) {
            next.focus();
        } else {
            form.submit();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

can i fix that , without delete my last js